# R-How dos the pos() function work for parts-of-speech tagging

Tags: r, string, tagging, qdap

I'm new to R and confused with the way the `pos()` function works. Here's why:

Example:

```
library(qdap)
s1<-c("Hello World")  
pos(s1)
```

This produces the correct output saying the word count

```
wrd.cnt - 2     
NN -1(50%) 
UH-1(50%)
```

whereas the following to operations throws errors:

```
s2<-"Hello"  
pos(s2)  

Error in apply(pro, 2, paster, digits = digits, symbol = s.ymb, override =   override) :   
  dim(X) must have a positive length  

s3<-c("Hello Hello")  
pos(s3)  

Error in apply(pro, 2, paster, digits = digits, symbol = s.ymb, override =   override) :   
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I'm not able to understand why this is caused.

Comment: what R package are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have found a bug in this version of **qdap** cause by not using `drop = FALSE` while indexing.

The dev version will behave as expected.  You can download it easily with this code:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_install_gh("trinker/qdap")
```

The following has been added to the `NEWS` file as well:

> - `pos` threw an error if only one word was passed to `text.var`.   Fix:
>     `drop = FALSE` has been added to data frame indexing.  Caught by 
>     StackOverflow user G_1991 [R-How dos the pos() function work for parts-of-speech tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29896488/1000343).

Here's the updated output:

```
library(qdap)
s1<-c("Hello World")  
pos(s1)  
##   wrd.cnt     NN     UH
## 1       2 1(50%) 1(50%)

s2<-"Hello"  
pos(s2)  
##   wrd.cnt      UH
## 1       1 1(100%)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. While trying to run the same, i.e p_install_gh("trinker/qdap")   , i got an error which said install RTools , which i did. Then , when i ran   find_rtools() , it says Rtools not installed although i have installed the correct version. Do you have any idea about this? Sorry for asking you an unrelated question.